# Show that sample mean diverges almost surely if the samples are i.i.d. sequences and one of the expectation of samples is infinite.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be an i.i.d. sequence with $E(X_1)=\infty$.
I have to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k=\infty$, but I don't know how to solve it... Please help me..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.